# Python / ImportError: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a python file to my application which is written in python.

I have the following code:

```
import os
from os.path import basename

class specificClass:
    def dothing(self,path):
          runcommand = __import__("/root/"+ os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]+ "/" + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0] +"/sa/update.py")
          runcommand.main()
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Comment: This error is also raised when trying to add a route in pyramid and you don't put the normal route path as 2nd parameter.
Example: config.add_route('admin_ajax_get_items', 'admin_ajax_get_items')   instead of config.add_route('admin_ajax_get_items', '/url/path')

Answer (score 12):

Instead of doing a import like `__import__` you can say

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path) # this is where your python file exists
import update
```

Comment: does that mean I am forced to add to path the folder where the package functions that I want to run are located at?

Say that there is one function I want to run in `..`, is there a way to import that function in **any** way?

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question, and generally promotes an extremely bad practice of modifying your system path within python modules.

Comment: What is the correct way of doing this?