# Including a Python Script in a Mac Cocoa Application: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: python, xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an OS X application that uses a Python script which imports a third-party library, `eyed3`. The script is called with `NSTask`, and works as intended if I use my Homebrew Python, which has `eyed3` installed via `pip`. This is expected.

I want to include all of this inside the application so the user does not need to have Homebrew, `eyed3`, or anything other than my `Application.app` file.

I have the python script, `EditChaptersScript.py`, included in my Xcode project, and I've included the `eyed3` framework in my Frameworks group, as shown in the link below.

[Image of Project Structure in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE3fn.png)

When I run the `NSTask`, and I pipe the output to my Xcode console, I get the following error: `/usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.`

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to get my script, with the framework it imports, included in my binary working with the system Python?

Comment: This looks interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997185/python-importerror-import-by-filename-is-not-supported