# Error when Submitting Job Training in Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm currently trying to submit a job training on Google Cloud ML with the Facenet (a Tensorflow library for face recognition). I'm currently trying this [(link is here)](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/wiki/Classifier-training-of-inception-resnet-v1)  part of the library where it does the training for the model.

Going to Google Cloud ML, I'm following this tutorial  [(link is here)](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/training-models)  where it teaches you how to submit a training.

I was able to successfully submit a job training to Google Cloud ML but there was an error.
Here are some pictures of the errors:

[image: Here's a picture of the error:]

And here's an error from the Google Cloud Jobs logs

[image: Here's a picture of error log in Google Cloud Jobs]

Here are more detailed pictures on Google Cloud Job logs

[image: Here are more detailed pictures on Google Cloud Job logs (1)]

[image: Here are more detailed pictures on Google Cloud Job logs (2)]

Submitting a job request was a success and it was even waiting for Tensorflow to start but right after that there's that error.

The commands I used to run this is here:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training facetraining_test4 \
--package-path=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/facenet/src/ \
--module-name=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/facenet/src/facenet_train_classifier.py \
--staging-bucket=gs://facenet-training-test \
--region=asia-east1 \
--config=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/facenet/none_config.yml  \
-- \
--logs_base_dir=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/logs/facenet/ \
--models_base_dir=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/models/facenet/ \
--data_dir=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/facenet_datasets/employee_dataset/employee/employee_maxpy_mtcnnpy_182/ \
--image_size=160 \
--model_def=models.inception_resnet_v1 \
--lfw_dir=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/facenet_datasets/lfw/lfw_mtcnnpy_160/ \
--optimizer=RMSPROP \
--learning_rate -1  \
--max_nrof_epochs=80 \
--keep_probability=0.8 \
--learning_rate_schedule_file=/Users/myname/Documents/projects/tf-projects/facenet/data/learning_rate_schedule_classifier_casia.txt \
--weight_decay=5e-5  \
--center_loss_factor=1e-4  \
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: If you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/mlengine/jobs you'll see a list of jobs and a link to the logs. Look for errors there and report back what you find.

Comment: Are you sure you are not returning a non-zero status code at the end of your training script? If not, I'd simply add some logging statements to your .py file and then check the logs in console.cloud.google.com/mlengine/jobs for your job to see where it is crashing.

Comment: @rhaertel80 I've added more pictures for a more detailed look at the errors.

Comment: @AmirHormati I'm quite new to the Google Cloud ML. I'm having a hard time trying to understand the errors. I've added pictures for a more detailed look at the errors. If you could help me understand the errors that would be great!

Comment: @Mikebarson Do you have the refactored version that can run on Cloud ML?

Answer (score 1):

When you are running on Cloud ML Engine you are running in a remote environment; so the file paths will not be the same as the local environment. If you need to import python modules you need to include them in the Python package you build and then import them using the package name.

For docs on how to build packages please refer to the [SetupTools docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html)

Here's the 30 second version

1. Organize your code as follows

```
    my_package/__init__.py
    my_package/moduleA.py
    my_package/moduleB.py
    my_package/...
    setup.py
```

2. For your setup.py file start with this

```
    from setuptools import find_packages
    from setuptools import setup

    REQUIRED_PACKAGES = []

    setup(
        name='my_package',
        version='0.1.1',
        author='Author',
        author_email='author@gmail.com',
        install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
        packages=find_packages(),
        description='Description',
        requires=[],)
```

3. Build a package as follows

```
python ./setup.py sdist
```

4. When the package is installed in Cloud ML Engine you will be able to import your code as

```
from my_package import moduleA
```

Comment: I see! So this applies to all the modules that it tries to import under facenet_train_classifier.py. What about those files like the '--log_base_dirs=...' those are the [USER_ARGS] section. Will I need to package those too?

Comment: @Mikebarson: yes, they need to be made accessible remotely. From the names of those particular args, they look like output directories, so should be paths on GCS. There is an under-documented gcloud command-line parameter, --job-dir. That directory will be passed to your programs as a command-line argument '--job-dir'. From there you can construct paths such as 'logs' and 'models'.

Comment: @rhaertel80 So you mean that I should put those '--log_base_dirs' and '--models_base_dirs' in a file. Then pass that file to '--job_dir'? How should I format those commands inside the file and what extension should I call the file?

Comment: @Mikebarson. There are two issues. (1) the output directories need to be locations on GCS (2) independent of that is how to pass those into the CloudML Engine. You can continue to use your own command-line args ('--log_base_dirs', '--models_base_dirs'), just make sure they point to a valid GCS bucket, something like, "gs://my-ml-bucket/job_x/log". Consider using the same bucket, but different 'sub-directory', as your input data.

Comment: @rhaertel80 I see. I did that actually. But Google Cloud couldn't locate it. I'll try again. So what's the use of '--job-dir'?

Comment: @Mikebarson. I need more info to be able to figure out why Google cloudn't locate it. For instance, you can't use os.path.exists on GCS paths (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42799952/1399222 for a solution). Regarding `--job-dir`, if you choose to use it, the service will ensure you have write permissions before running your job and then pass it through to your binary as `--job-dir` (so be sure to parse it). Then you can use it to build sub-directories for logs and models, e.g., `model_dir = os.path.join(args.job_dir, 'model')`

Comment: @rhaertel80 Alright. I don't think I've used os.path.exists. It also left me wondering why it couldn't locate the directories when they're already in the bucket. About the `--job-dir` I'm still a bit confused. When should I use `--job-dir` and why?

Comment: @Mikebarson. In general, you can't use any regular file operations from the standard library (glob, list exists, mkdir), so check that, too. What's the exact error? `--job-dir` is a convenience function for allowing the service to verify the permissions. It should also create subdirectories for you during hyperparameter tuning so that you don't have to manage that yourself and risk overwriting previous output.

Comment: @rhaertel80 So if my file contains any of those operations, it would likely result to an error? So `--job-dir` is used for verification of permissions and creation of sub-dirs during hyperparamater tuning.  I'm using the hyperparameter tuning so that probably won't be something I'll need using for now. Can you perhaps check this [https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/facenet_train_classifier.py]. That's what I'm using to run the job which is shown above. Taking note what Jermey Lewi said, I need to package the files that are being imported in this file for it to work.

Comment: Your problem likely stems from the calls to `os.path.isdir()` and `os.path.makedirs()`. You should be able to safely replace those with the equivalent functionality in `file_io.py` (see SO link in previous comment for more info). Those changes will still work with local runs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message above, it seems that you issue is related to "ImportError: import by filename is not supported" error from Python. Without looking at your python source code, I can't tell you exactly how to fix it but the following link should solve your issue:

[Python / ImportError: Import by filename is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997185/python-importerror-import-by-filename-is-not-supported)

In general look for places that you are importing using file paths and make sure you are using the functions correctly.

Comment: Could it be that Google can't find the files? This was working properly in my local terminal.

Comment: When you are running on Cloud ML Engine you are running in a remote environment; so the file paths will not be the same as the local environment. If you need to import python modules you write you need to include them in the Python package you build and then import them using the package name.

Comment: @JeremyLewi can you show me an example? That would really help! Thanks! :D

Comment: I added an answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks! @JeremyLewi I'll be testing your solutions soon.