# Google ML. Reading data and accessing specific folders from the Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

So far to manage getting data from the bucket I use download_to_file() to get it downloaded on the instance that it is using and access the files/folders locally. Though what I want to achieve is being able to just read from the cloud. How can I go about doing that? There doesn't seem to be a way for me create a relative path from the ML Job instance and the google cloud bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TensorFlow's [`file_io.FileIO`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py#L32) class to create file_like objects to read/write files on gcs, local, or any other supported file system.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799952/1399222) for some examples.

Comment: I've been exploring google storage's blob documentation https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage-blobs.html . When you attach a file from GCS to a 'blob' is it readable as that file by the system?

Comment: If you use that class, you'll have to use one of the methods on the class, e.g. `download_as_string` or `download_to_file`. While downloading the file may make sense in some cases, generally you'll use TensorFlow readers (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#reading_from_files) in which case you're just providing GCS paths to the readers.