# Unable to download Google Cloud Storage file from the trainer application in Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to download a file from Cloud Storage from my trainer application which runs in Cloud ML engine. However I'm getting the following error when I try to download the file.
I do have access to the Cloud Storage path.

Error:

```
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 482, in download_to_filename self.download_to_file(file_obj, client=client) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 464, in download_to_file self._do_download(transport, file_obj, download_url, headers) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 418, in _do_download download.consume(transport) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 101, in consume self._write_to_stream(result) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 62, in _write_to_stream with response: AttributeError: __exit__
```

Here is the code for downloading the GCS file:

```
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(key)
  blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

I'm not providing any GCP credentials to `Client` as the trainer application running can access other files using

```
tf.train.string_input_producer
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trainer application accesses other files via TensorFlow's [file_io](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py) module.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799952/1399222) has a few tips, but if you want to open a file:

```
with file_io.FileIO("gs://my_bucket/myfile") as f:
  f.read()
```

There is also a `copy(..)` function and `read_file_to_string(...)`, if those fit your needs better.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. Not sure why it doesn't work with the way I was trying.