# gcloud ml-engine IOError: file does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, keras, google-cloud-ml

My jobs in gcloud ml-engine crash because the train file doesn't exist. In the screenshot you can see the error in the top line. At the bottom I check the contents of the directory and the file is clearly there.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT5Fo.jpg)

[source](https://gist.github.com/btocoolman/0763a43428457f4fc8c5c19e786fef1e)

Comment: I don't think pandas supports reading files directly from gcloud, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does not have native GCS support. If the pandas method you are using accepts file object, then you can use the TensorFlow file_io library to open the file. See the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799117/google-cloud-ml-and-gcs-bucket-issues/42799952#42799952). If not, then you can copy the file to VM first using gsutil cli.